# XSLT 2.0 transformation

Tags: xslt

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
    <wd:Report_Data 
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CIS_CR_INT122_HMS_Dependent_Report"> 
    <wd:Report_Entry>
    <wd:Dependents>
     <wd:project_id>2269</wd:project_id>
     <wd:plan_id>5909</wd:plan_id>
     <wd:employee_client_id>JA5637</wd:employee_client_id>
    </wd:Dependents>
    </wd:Report_Entry> 
    <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Dependents>
              <wd:project_id>2269</wd:project_id>
              <wd:plan_id>5909</wd:plan_id>
              <wd:employee_client_id>JA4345</wd:employee_client_id>
        </wd:Dependents>
     </wd:Report_Entry>
     <wd:Report_Entry>
        <wd:Dependents>
              <wd:project_id>2269</wd:project_id>
              <wd:plan_id>5909</wd:plan_id>
              <wd:employee_client_id>JA5637</wd:employee_client_id>
         </wd:Dependents>
         </wd:Report_Entry>
         </wd:Report_Data>
```

The XLST is not working. It is not displaying , separator or new line . I also need need to remove duplicate employee_client_id. Ex JA5637 came twice i need remove that using XSLT. Every dependent should be in one new row with comma separator. see the output below

sample xslt i built

```
         <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
         <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
         xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
         exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
         version="2.0">

            <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>    
            <xsl:variable name="NEWLINE">
            <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="DELIMITER">,</xsl:variable>
            <xsl:output method="text"/>

             <xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data" 
              xmlns:wd="urn:com.comday.report/INT007BOutbound">
               <!--These are just text column headers for output-->
               <xsl:text>project_id,plan_id,employee_client_id</xsl:text>
               <xsl:value-of select="$NEWLINE"/>
               <xsl:for-each select="wd:Report_Entry">
               <xsl:for-each select="wd:Dependents">
               <xsl:value-of select="wd:project_id"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$DELIMITER"/>
                <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="wd:plan_id"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$DELIMITER"/>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                   <xsl:value-of select="wd:employee_client_id"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$NEWLINE"/>
                    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
                   </xsl:for-each>
                  </xsl:template>
                 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

output

project-id,plan_id,employee_client_id

2269, 5909, JA5637

2269,5909,JA4345

Answer (score 1):

yes i got it

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>    
<xsl:variable name="NEWLINE">
    <xsl:text>&#13;&#10;</xsl:text>
</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="DELIMITER">,</xsl:variable>
<xsl:output method="text"/>

<xsl:template match="wd:Report_Data" xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CIS_CR_INT122_HMS_Dependent_Report">
    <!--These are just text column headers for output-->
    <xsl:text>project_id,plan_id,employee_client_id</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$NEWLINE"/>
    <xsl:for-each-group select="wd:Report_Entry/wd:Dependents" group-by="wd:employee_client_id">
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:project_id"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$DELIMITER"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:plan_id"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$DELIMITER"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:employee_client_id"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="$DELIMITER"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="wd:employee_name"/>
```

Comment: thanks a lot michael, i figured that out but did not post and answer. I real thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your XML declares:

```
xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday.report/CIS_CR_INT122_HMS_Dependent_Report"
```

but you do:

```
xmlns:wd="urn:com.comday.report/INT007BOutbound"
```

As a result, your template does not match anything in the input XML, and the entire output you see is generated by the [built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#built-in-rule).

---

I did not check the rest of your stylesheet. Still, I would add that in XSLT 2.0 you can use [`xpath-default-namespace`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#standard-attributes) instead of a prefix.